# "No Kernel Error" when doing a EFI install

Tags: 11.10, installation, uefi

I created a Multi boot USB for my Ubuntu & Windows 7 install using the steps in [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28857/10247) (code below)

Difference is I used GParted instead of command line to do partitioning. And I used Ubuntu Alternate iso instead. I could get to the install screens but at Install Base System, I get no available kernel in repositories error. I didn't find anyway to select & install a kernel.

What might be wrong? And how can I solve this?

---

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
create new MBR, 'o' command
create new partition, part 1, size 8G, type ef, set bootable, write
mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdc1
mkdir /mnt/USB
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/USB
insert Windows 7 x64 DVD, again, mine appeared as /media/UDF\ Volume, you need to change references below
# Extract/Copy the entire Windows DVD to the USB
cp -r /media/UDF\ Volume/* /mnt/USB
# I don't know what effect the following rename has, I copied blindly from another webpage.
mv /mnt/USB/sources/ei.cfg /mnt/USB/sources/ei.cfg_
cd /mnt/USB/efi/microsoft/boot/
7z e /mnt/USB/sources/install.wim 1/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
cp -r /mnt/USB/efi/microsoft/boot /mnt/USB/efi/
mv /mnt/USB/efi/boot/bootmgfw.efi /mnt/USB/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
# At this point I booted the USB, and installed Windows 7 to a GPT SSD
# Upon reboot I noticed the Windows Boot loader in my UEFI boot list (actually it made itself 1st).
# so, here we have a standalone Windows7 UEFI installer that will function correctly (64bit ASUS, at least).
# Now, on to adding Ubuntu
cd /mnt/USB
7z x /path2iso/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso
# If 7z finds prexisting files with the same name, just allow always overwrite
# (Y)es / (N)o / (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit? A

# At this point I booted the USB, and installed Ubuntu x64 to a GPT SSD
# we have a standalone Ubuntu 64bit installer that install Ubuntu 64

# Now, on to add a boot manager that will allow us to select between Windows 7 and Ubuntu

# Get the target UUID of the USB partition, using either blkid or the following command
grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /mnt/USB/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi  
will print YOUR_UUID # Substitute into the following references to YOUR_UUID

# Append the following menuentry to /mnt/USB/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg

menuentry "Microsoft Windows x86_64 UEFI-GPT Setup" {
    insmod usbms  
    insmod part_gpt  
    insmod part_msdos  
    insmod fat  
    insmod search_fs_uuid  
    insmod chain  
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root YOUR_UUID # <- CHANGE THIS TO YOUR UUID
    chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should try the amd64+mac image instead? As I understand it, it's for EFI machines. You can find it here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/release/

Comment: It appears that version is no longer available? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download

Comment: It is. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad  Have a similar issue as OP here but you have provided a link only answer presented as a question.  Could you explain to how you come to the understanding that using the +mac iso would be beneficial and recommendable on an amd64 platform?  OP asked What might be wrong? And how can I solve this?  Can you provide a more convincing answer rather than a suggested "might work" solution?  Not all EFI machines are Mac's!